# Vanilla JS remove a specific class from all elements that hold it

Tags: javascript

```js
let els = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-button");

Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {

    let elem = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);

    elem.classList.toggle("no-rounded-bottom");
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --bg-head-acc-root: #00667c;
  --bg-body-acc-root: #004d5d;
}

textarea:hover,
input:hover,
textarea:active,
input:active,
textarea:focus,
input:focus,
label:focus,
button:focus,
button:active,
button:hover,
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  outline: 0px !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

div#accordionElements div.accordion-item {
  background-color: var(--bg-body-acc-root);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div#accordionElements button.accordion-button {
  background-color: var(--bg-head-acc-root);
  color: #f5f5f5;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.accordion-button:after {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

ul.ListaMultiplaBorder {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #044533;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #00667c;
}

.text-label-schede {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  color: #5f9daa;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.no-rounded-bottom {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionElements">

  <div class="accordion-item border-0 my-4">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading21">
      <button id="mr-21"
           class="accordion-button py-2 collapsed" 
             dir="rtl" 
             type="button" 
             data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
             data-bs-target="#r-21" 
             aria-expanded="false" 
             aria-controls="r-21">
        <div class="row w-100">
          <div class="col-2 recordstatus">
            <p class="m-0 text-end">
              <img src="/assets/images/ico_accesso_si.png" alt="" title="Attivo">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <h3 class="m-0 ms-3 py-2 fs-5">AAAA</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="r-21" 
         class="accordion-collapse collapse" 
         aria-labelledby="heading21" 
         data-bs-parent="#accordionElements" style="">
      <div class="accordion-body px-0 pt-0">
        <p class="text-white p-3">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item border-0 my-4">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading22">
      <button id="mr-22" 
           class="accordion-button py-2 collapsed" 
              dir="rtl" 
              type="button" 
              data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
              data-bs-target="#r-22" 
              aria-expanded="false" 
              aria-controls="r-22">
        <div class="row w-100">
          <div class="col-2 recordstatus">
            <p class="m-0 text-end">
              <img src="/assets/images/ico_accesso_si.png" alt="" title="Attivo">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-10">
            <h3 class="m-0 ms-3 py-2 fs-5">BBBBB</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="r-22" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading22" data-bs-parent="#accordionElements">
      <div class="accordion-body px-0 pt-0">
        <p class="text-white p-3">Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have a function that adds the "no-rounded-bottom" class if it doesn't exist or deletes it if it exists, I would need when I click on one of these elements, remove the same class from all elements that have that class before this operation.

```
const clickElem = elClass => {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll(elClass);

  Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
      let elem = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
      elem.classList.toggle("no-rounded-bottom");
    });
  });
};
```

I added the snippet, if you always click on the same element, on opening the rounded edges below are reset, at the second click the element closes and the edges below are rounded again, if instead the second click I do it on the second element the first closes but the corners below are not rounded, what I want is that when you click on any element the previous one open always closes and that the corners below are rounded again, I hope I have explained

Comment: I don't find it really clear... why don't you show a mini example of what you have, [as it is recommended to do in such a case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: i have add a snippet in teh original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `classList.toggle()` return a boolean value
2. `classList.toggle(class, force )` use a  boolean force
3. `.querySelectorAll()` have a `forEach()`  a method
4. `forEach()` method may have 3 arguments, the last one reffer to the used array

- you don't need to have ids for your elements...
- as you are using an arrow function in your event listener, you also don't need to use `e.currentTarget` to refer  `el`

also, in your code:
`document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id)`
*or* `e.currentTarget`
*or* `el`
are exactly the same DOM element

code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-button').forEach((el,i,arr) =>
  {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
    if (el.classList.toggle('no-rounded-bottom')) // flip class, then return (class added)?true:false
      arr.forEach( elArr =>                      // arr = querySelectorAll('.accordion-button')
        elArr.classList.toggle('no-rounded-bottom', el === elArr ) // add or remove
      )                                         //  class according to force test
    })
  })
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-button').forEach((el,i,arr) =>
  {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => 
    {
    if (el.classList.toggle('no-rounded-bottom'))
      arr.forEach( elArr =>
        elArr.classList.toggle('no-rounded-bottom', el === elArr ) 
      )
    })
  })
```

```css
:root {
  --bg-head-acc-root: #00667c;
  --bg-body-acc-root: #004d5d;
  }
textarea:hover,
input:hover,
textarea:active,
input:active,
textarea:focus,
input:focus,
label:focus,
button:focus,
button:active,
button:hover,
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  outline            : 0px !important;
  -webkit-appearance : none;
  box-shadow         : none !important;
  }
div#accordionElements div.accordion-item {
  background-color : var(--bg-body-acc-root);
  border-radius    : 10px;
  }
div#accordionElements button.accordion-button {
  background-color : var(--bg-head-acc-root);
  color            : #f5f5f5;
  text-shadow      : 1px 1px #000;
  border-radius    : 10px;
  }
.accordion-button:after {
  filter      : brightness(0) invert(1);
  }
ul.ListaMultiplaBorder {
  padding     : 0 15px;
  border-top  : 1px solid #044533;
  box-shadow  : inset 0 1px 0 #00667c;
  }
.text-label-schede {
  text-shadow : 0 1px 1px #000;
  color       : #5f9daa;
  font-weight : normal;
  }
.no-rounded-bottom {
  border-bottom-left-radius  : 0 !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius : 0 !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionElements">

    <div class="accordion-item border-0 my-4">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading21">
        <button id="mr-21"
             class="accordion-button py-2 collapsed" 
               dir="rtl" 
               type="button" 
               data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
               data-bs-target="#r-21" 
               aria-expanded="false" 
               aria-controls="r-21">
          <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col-2 recordstatus">
              <p class="m-0 text-end">
                <img src="/assets/images/ico_accesso_si.png" alt="" title="Attivo">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
              <h3 class="m-0 ms-3 py-2 fs-5">AAAA</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="r-21" 
           class="accordion-collapse collapse" 
           aria-labelledby="heading21" 
           data-bs-parent="#accordionElements" style="">
        <div class="accordion-body px-0 pt-0">
          <p class="text-white p-3">Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="accordion-item border-0 my-4">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading22">
        <button id="mr-22" 
             class="accordion-button py-2 collapsed" 
                dir="rtl" 
                type="button" 
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                data-bs-target="#r-22" 
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-controls="r-22">
          <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col-2 recordstatus">
              <p class="m-0 text-end">
                <img src="/assets/images/ico_accesso_si.png" alt="" title="Attivo">
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
              <h3 class="m-0 ms-3 py-2 fs-5">BBBBB</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="r-22" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading22" data-bs-parent="#accordionElements">
        <div class="accordion-body px-0 pt-0">
          <p class="text-white p-3">Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: I always wondered how that second param on `.toggle()` could be of any use.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been a source of inspiration.
If you have time, I could better understand the part that refers to (el, i, arr)

Comment: @Robert these are simply the parameters of the callback function (here an arrow function) and correspond respectively to the arguments : `element`, `index` and `array` indicated in the mdn documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of what your last opened accordion was so that you can remove the `no-rounded-bottom` class from it when you open another element. So you can have something like this in your JS:

```js
let lastSelectedElement = null;

const clickElem = elClass => {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll(elClass);

  Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", e => {
      let elem = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
      elem.classList.toggle("no-rounded-bottom");

      if (lastSelectedElement) {
        lastSelectedElement.classList.toggle("no-rounded-bottom");
      }

      lastSelectedElement = elem;
    });
  });
};
```

This way, you can always ensure that the last accordion opened will always remove the `no-rounded-bottom` class.